# Double integral over a single variable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

How to reduce

$\int_0^t\Big(\int^s_0y(r)dr\Big)ds$

to

$\int_0^t\Big(\int^t_ry(r)ds\Big)dr$

using Fubini's theorem?

Comment: Is your problem to see that the limits are as they are? If so, what if you draw a picture with the $r$ and $s$ axes, and fill the domain (which is a triangle)? Or is your problem on how to verify that it is allowed to switch order of integration?

Comment: @mickep yes, I cannot see how to obtain the new limits

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I understand your question completely, but I give it a go:

Reading your first integral,
$$
\int_0^t\biggl(\int_0^s y(r)\,dr\biggr)\,ds
$$
we see that we should first integrate the $r$ variable, and it should run from $r=0$ to $r=s$. Then, we should integrate the $s$ variable from $s=0$ to $s=t$. This gives the triangle below.

[image: axes]

If we instead want to integrate the $s$ variable first, looking at the picture that we now got, we find that the lower limit of $s$ is $s=r$, and the upper limit is $s=t$. Once that is determined, the lower limit of $r$ is $r=0$ and the upper limit is $r=t$ (note that we have already taken care of the line $s=r$, so we only look at the smallest and largest values that $r$ can take). Thus, we end up with
$$
\int_0^t\biggl(\int_r^t y(r)\,ds\biggr)\,dr.
$$
Finally, since your $y$ only depends on $r$, the last integral can be simplified (integrating in $s$) to
$$
\int_0^t (t-r)y(r)\,dr.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let's read the integration endpoints from inside out: the inner integral tells us that $0 \le r \le s$. The outer one tells us that $0 \le s \le t$. Putting these together, we get $0 \le r \le s \le t$.

Now, if there are $4$ variables and you want to make inequalities with just $3$ of them, how many such inequalities are there? Well, $\binom 4 3 = 4$ and since we have already written $2$ of them above, let us look for the remaining $2$.

First, I pick $0 \le r \le t$; now, what does $s$ do? Well, $r \le s \le t$. The inequality $0 \le r \le t$ translates to $\int \limits _0 ^t \dots \Bbb d r$. The other one translates to $\int \limits _r ^t \dots \Bbb d s$. Since $r$ is an integration variable in the first integral and an endpoint in the second, it is obvious that the first one will be the outer one, and the second one the inner one: $\int \limits _0 ^t \big( \int \limits _r ^t \dots \Bbb d s \big) \Bbb d r$.